# Unable To connect when uploading bigger files to mysql database using laravel and mamp

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, apache, mamp

I have a problem while uploading files into my apache server, the navigator keeps showing the message the connection was reset. I've tried with little files (100kb), it works just fine, but when I tried 500kb or more files the connection was reset...

Here is my php.ini settings for uploads :

upload_max_filesize = 320M

memory_limit = 12800M

max_input_time = 6000

max_execution_time = 3000

post_max_size = 300M

default_socket_timeout = 600

The form Code :

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" method="POST" action="{{ url('FruitCreate') }}" >
{{ csrf_field() }}
<input type="text" name='name'>
<input type="text" name='price'>
<input type="hidden" name="MAX_FILE_SIZE" value="30000000" />
<input type="file" name='image'>
<select name='quantitytype'>
    <option value='unity'> unity </option>
    <option value='kg'> kg </option>
</select>   

<button type='submit'> submit </button>
```

here is my Controller for entering a new line to the db :

```
class fruitController extends Controller
public function createFruit(Request $request){
$file = $request->file('image'); 

$fruit = new fruit;

$imageContent = $file->openFile()->fread($file->getSize()); 
$fruit = new fruit;
$fruit->picture = $imageContent;
$fruit->name = $request->name;
$fruit->quantitytype = $request->quantitytype;
$fruit->price = $request->price; 
$fruit->save();
return redirect('FruitsChangingPricePanel');
//
```

Thanks for your help !!!!!

Comment: I would not store images into the database, but rather store them in a folder and store the path location to the file in the database.